# causing updates to SpinnerNumberModel even if the number is the same

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, changelistener

I have a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) and some [`ChangeListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html)s.

But the ChangeListeners only get notified when the spinner number changes. Is there a way to initiate an event that propagates to the ChangeListeners even if the new spinner number is the same as the previous value?

Comment: Why would you invoke a change listener when no change has happened?

Comment: Because the model may become out of sync with "reality" due to other events I don't have access to, and I want to reinitialize the model and ensure that downstream actions occur. (In effect there is a NaN state that I can't use because SpinnerNumberModel doesn't support it, though I can't detect it anyway until the next non-NaN state occurs.)

Comment: Not sure I completely understand: when you do the sync with reality, isn't that the point when change happens and when an event should be sent?

Comment: My NumberModel represents a counter on a remote device. Let's say it's 10. There are occasions where the remote device's counter changes and I can't detect that. But I have a later time ("sync with reality" as described earlier) where I still don't know the remote device's counter, but I set it to a value. If that value is 10, even if the NumberModel already contains 10, I want to `fireUpdate()` (per my new implementation) and cause that to propagate to the remote device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpinnerNumberModel sends an event to the registered change listeners in exactly these methods:

```
1. public void setValue(Object value)
2. public void setStepSize(Number stepSize)
3. public void setMaximum(Comparable maximum)
4. public void setMinimum(Comparable minimum)
```

In each of these methods, an event is only issued iff the value passed as the parameter actually differs from the current value.

However, you could write your own `SpinnerModel` (e.g. by subclassing `SpinnerNumberModel`) and fire all the events you want. If your implementation inherits from `AbstractSpinnerModel`, as `SpinnerNumberModel` does, you'll have a handy `fireStateChanged` method available for sending events:

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractSpinnerModel.html#fireStateChanged()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractSpinnerModel.html#fireStateChanged%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Thomas beat me to it, but I came to the same conclusion and here's what I ended up doing:

```
private static class SpinnerNumberModel2 extends SpinnerNumberModel
{
    public SpinnerNumberModel2(int value, int minimum, int maximum, int stepSize)
    {
        super(value,minimum,maximum,stepSize);
    }
    public void fireUpdate() { super.fireStateChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Note that you don't even have to use a different method name to make fireStateChanged() public.